# How to iterate over a list of genes/URLs and generate rows of gene information?

Tags: python, loops

I am new to Python and not familiar with loop structure.
If I want to iterate over a list of urls of my gene of interest and extract specific columns (for example gene name, full gene name, and its biotype from that website) as a row

```
gene1  full_name1  biotype1
```

and add new rows for next genes like below

```
gene1  full_name1  biotype1
gene2  full_name2  biotype2
gene3  full_name3  biotype3
...
```

I am not sure how to do this. Perhaps I should use multiple loops?

Here is my code:

```
gene_list = [gene1, gene2, gene3, ...]
i = 0
while (i in len(gene_list):
    url = 'https://www.xxxxxxxx?gene=' + str(gene_list[i])
    driver.get(url)
    gene = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('em:nth-of-type(1)').text
    full = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h2:nth-of-type(1)').text
    biotype = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.gc-category').text
    i = i + 1
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: "I am new to Python and not familiar with loop structure." This is the crux of the problem. Your should spend some time on a basic tutorial rather than essentially asking for someone here to explain it. What you have is not a programming issue that you have diligently tried to solve, but a failure to do basic research. That's off topic on this site.

Comment: @MadPhysicist OP demonstrated a reasonable effort. While StackOverflow is about questions on programming, the website shouldn't be so unfriendly to those who are beginning. For someone who is new, dealing with a tutorial on the entirety of Python when there is a specific use case is simply unfeasible, and suggesting that instead of simply welcoming OP and providing an answer is unfriendly and will simply push others away from programming.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a for-loop.

First create the url list using a list comprehension.

```
gene_list = [gene1, gene2, gene3, ...]
url_list = ['https://www.xxxxxxxx?gene={}'.format(i) for i in gene_list]
```

Next, initialize empty lists of each of your columns.

```
genes = []
full_names = []
biotypes = []
```

Finally, for each url in the url list, you'll pull the information and append them to their individual lists.

```
for url in url_list:
    driver.get(url)
    genes.append(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('em:nth-of-type(1)').text)
    full_names.append(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h2:nth-of-type(1)').text)
    biotypes.append(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.gc-category').text)
```

If you want to get fancy from there, you can put it into a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([gene_list, genes, full_names, biotypes])
```

Once it is in a pandas DataFrame, you will be able to play with and visualize the data much more easily and prettily.

Comment: Thank you, Yehuda. It's very nice of you. I get an `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` on this line `url_list = ['https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene={}'.format(gene_list[i]) for i in gene_list]` 
What might be the problem...

Comment: Now it works with `url_list = ['https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene={}'.format(i) for i in test_list]`!

Although the rows and columns should be transposed in the final pandas data frame output.

Comment: @Helena My apologies, a silly mistake. I corrected it in the answer. Re: transposition, chain a `.transpose()` method at the end of the dataframe definition, like so: `df = pd.DataFrame([gene_list, genes, full_names, biotypes]).transpose()`. That should look right. If this answer helped you, consider clicking the check mark to give it credit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gene_list = [gene1, gene2, gene3, ...]
i = 0
gene_info = []
while i < len(gene_list):
    url = 'https://www.xxxxxxxx?gene=' + str(gene_list[i])
    driver.get(url)
    gene = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('em:nth-of-type(1)').text
    full = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h2:nth-of-type(1)').text
    biotype = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.gc-category').text
    gene_info.append([gene, full, biotype])
    i = i + 1
print(gene_info)
```